# Jq to replace a word with in the json

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have a json below and i need to fetch the value of the key "toModify" in data section. And also wanted to modify the key(toModify) value with another value Ex: hello1234567 to xyz. How can we do that using jq.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": "12334"        
      },
      "data": {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test",        
        "cData": [
          {
            "key": "keOne",
            "value": "hello"
          },
          {
            "key": "toModify",
            "value": "hello1234567"
          }
        ]
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked similar questions? Have you read a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Your input, specifically the value of the `cData` key, looks tailor-made to be used with `to_entries` and `from_entries`.

```
$ jq '.items[0].data.cData |= (from_entries | .toModify = "xyz" | to_entries)' tmp.json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": "12334"
      },
      "data": {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test",
        "cData": [
          {
            "key": "keOne",
            "value": "hello"
          },
          {
            "key": "toModify",
            "value": "xyz"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Warning: the proposed solution assumes the key names are distinct.

Comment: Ugh, yes, let's hope so :)

Comment: I toyed a little with trying to use `select(.key == "toModify)`, but didn't really pursue it; that would let you change each object while preserving duplicates, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are a bit sketchy, but the following produces the desired result in this particular case, and illustrates one approach:

```
.items[].data.cData
  |= map(if .key == "toModify" then .key = "MODIFIED" else . end)
```